# Unable to stream file upload through controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, file-upload

I'm trying to effectively proxy a file upload via an ASP.NET Core 5 MVC controller to another API:

```
[DisableFormValueModelBinding]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload()
{
    var reader = new MultipartReader(Request.GetMultipartBoundary(), Request.Body);

    MultipartSection section;

    while ((section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)) != null)
    {
        if (section.ContentType == "application/json")
        {
            await SendFile(section.Body);
        }
    }

    return View("Upload");
}

private async Task SendFile(Stream stream)
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://blah/upload");

    request.Content = new StreamContent(stream);

    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
}
```

However, the receiving API always gets an empty stream.

I can confirm the `SendFile` method works as the following test works from within the controller method:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream("test.json", FileMode.Open))
{
    await SendFile(fs);
}
```

And I can see the uploaded file if I try to read it in the controller:

```
var buf = new char[256];

using (var sr = new StreamReader(section.Body))
{
    var x = await sr.ReadAsync(buf, 0, buf.Length);

    while (x > 0)
    {
        log.Debug(new string(buf));
        
        x = await sr.ReadAsync(buf, 0, buf.Length);
    }
}
```

So both ends seem to work, just not together.

I have `EnableBuffering` set:

```
app.Use(next => context =>
{
    context.Request.EnableBuffering();

    return next(context);
});
```

And I'm disabling binding of the uploaded files to the model using the `DisableFormValueModelBindingAttribute` example from [Upload files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

I've also tried rewinding the stream manually using `Seek`, but it doesn't make a difference.

It works if I copy it through a `MemoryStream`:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    await section.Body.CopyToAsync(ms);
    await ms.FlushAsync();
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    await SendFile(ms);
}
```

However, this buffers the file in memory which is not suitable for large files.

It also works if I read the uploaded file first, rewind and then try:

```
var buf = new char[256];

using (var sr = new StreamReader(section.Body))
{
    var x = await sr.ReadAsync(buf, 0, buf.Length);

    while (x > 0)
    {
        log.Debug(new string(buf));
        
        x = await sr.ReadAsync(buf, 0, buf.Length);
    }
}

section.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

// this works now:

await SendFile(section.Body);
```

Again, this is not suitable for large files.

It seems the stream is not in the correct state to be consumed by my `SendFile` method but I cannot see why.

**UPDATE**

Based on comments from Jeremy Lakeman I took a closer look at what was happening with the stream length.

I discovered that removing `EnableBuffering` makes it work as expected, so the issue is sort of resolved by that.

However, I came across this [aspnetcore Github comment](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/3476#issuecomment-483871281) where a contributor states that:

> We don't support flowing the Request Body through as a stream to HttpClient.

That and the other comments in that issue support Jeremy's comments about `CanSeek` and the stream length, and it's unclear (to me) whether this should actually work and whether it's just a coincidence that it now does (i.e. will I get hit with another gotcha later).

In this specific scenario with MIME multipart, where we don't know the stream length without buffering/counting the whole file, is there an alternative to `StreamContent` or a different way to handle the file upload?

The Microsoft docs page [Upload files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0) advises only to *use an alternative approach*. It talks about streaming uploads, however, it stops short of properly consuming the stream and just buffers the file into a `MemoryStream` (completely defeating the purpose of streaming)

Comment: Are you receiving the source stream as a chunked transfer? In which case the source stream length wouldn't be available, which might be causing issues with `StreamContent`.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman no, the request is not being chunked. Content-Length is correctly sent and captured in the request headers. The stream length is 0 prior to being accessed and is the expected value after the stream is processed, in both cases (i.e. successful test read and unsuccessful onward POST).

Comment: I haven't used `MultipartReader`, this is multipart mime? with boundary strings? Yeah, there's no way that `section.Body.Length` to be set to a known value before the stream is read. So `StreamContent` is likely seeing 0, even though data is available. If `section.Body.CanSeek` then `StreamContent` is likely to do the wrong thing.